# Is inserting images broken?

Tags: bug, markdown, images, uploader

I was trying to edit a fresh user's post to include the image in the post.

So I clicked on edit, then at the appropriate position CTRL-G, switched to "paste" and inserted `https://i.imgur.com/lT8q3Ks.png`.

That inserted the following markdown:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

and, at the end of the rendered post:

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUEZC.png
```

This is what it looks like in the post:

[image]

This is the post I'm referring to: [How to fix: SELECT element only returns the first option's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56181011/how-to-fix-select-element-only-returns-the-first-options-value)

Did I do anything wrong, or do imgur images just work differently due to imgur integration? How do I actually insert that image properly using the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't finish your code block with

````
```
````

So the `[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUEZC.png` is still part of the code block, and the Markdown renderer doesn't treat it as a reference.

But you do have a point; the image uploader isn't smart enough to detect this situation, it'll just append the reference without checking if it will actually be rendered. In the old situation, where code formatting with fences wasn't supported, only the four-spaces method, this would never happen since the reference always started after an extra newline which ends the code block.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. Didn't realize I had to fix that error in the original post first to be able to insert images above that. Makes sense though.

Comment: This is a slightly unusual situation where both you and the uploader are 'at fault', see the update.

Comment: Do you think this should be fixed? Or is SO position on this "shit in- shit out"?

Comment: If you leave the [bug] tag, someone of the developers will have a look at it eventually and decide whether it's worth fixing. (FWIW, the professional version of that phrase is "garbage in, garbage out".)